# sort and count values in a column DataFrame (Python Pandas)

Tags: pandas, jupyter

I have the next DataFrame

df

[image]

I count the values this way

[image]

I want to have the category values in the next order:

**1.0**   *1*

**4.0**   *1*

**7.0**   *2*

**10.0**   *1*

and so on ...

In the ascending way with their respect amount of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by index using `sort_index()`

```
df['col_1'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort on the index after calling value_counts. here's an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,2,2,1,4,5,5,4,3,5,6,3]})
df['x'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Output:

```
1    2
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    1
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Created Data frame having values as below :

[image]

and then sort it via below code ,below is output shown

```
df1.groupby(by=['Cat']).count().sort_values(by='col1')
```

[image]